# Two problems form metric topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the next two problems in metric topology and would need help, since i have no idea how to start or solve them.

1st problem:

Given an example to show that the closure of an open sphere

```
S(p,δ) = {x : d(p,x)<δ}
```

need not be "closed sphere"

```
Ṡ(p,δ) = {x : d(p,x)≤δ}
```

dot over letter S should be line.

2nd problem:

Show that the following is a norm on

```
C[0,1] = ||f|| = |_integr_{{0};{1};{|abs{f({x})} dx}}
```

Here is the image of second problems equation: http://i60.tinypic.com/o9pg6u.png for better representation.

Thanks

Comment: Would you say this is appropriate and suficcient solution for problem 1 http://tinypic.com/r/n6xtlw/8 and this http://tinypic.com/r/swz802/8 for problem 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Consider the distance: $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ ; $d(x,y)=1$ if not. This is the distance of discrete topology: all subsets are open.

Then the open ball $B(x,1)$ contains only $x$ though the closed ball $B(x,1)$ contains all points.

2  firstly, a positive continue function (which is the case of the absolute value of $f$) of integral $0$ is $0$ everywhere.

secondly, $\int af=a\int f$

thirdly, use the triangular inequality in $\mathbb{R}$ and the positivity of integral.

Comment: Thanks, would there be any chance that you could possibly solve this and present me with solutions. I feel really stupid but i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: you mean the second one?

Comment: Well honestly both dazzle me. But any would help a lot.

Comment: I have added some details.